# What is the motivation for setting $v \cdot v = \|v\|^2$ for $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Recently, we discussed inner products in my Linear Algebra course. We state:

$v \cdot v = ||v||^2$ for $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ Why can we say this?

We later define the norm as $||v|| = \sqrt{\langle v, v}$ for $v \in V$. How can we say that (1) $||v|| \ge 0$ when we only know that $||v||^2 \ge 0$ from the axioms, and how do we known $\langle v, v \rangle = ||v||^2$ in the first place?

We also state that $\langle v, w \rangle = 0$ iff $v, w$ are "orthogonal". What enables us to say this statement?

Comment: Note that $x^2 \geq 0$ implies $x \geq 0$ by the so-called "trivial inequality." Everything else, you have to provide a definition - there's no reason behind definitions. You also don't say that a single vector is "orthogonal," but rather pairs or sets of vectors.

Comment: But the definition of magnitude has to make sense, right? I'm wondering why the dot product seems to "magically" give the square of the magnitude ... like is there a mathematical reason?

Comment: @user129393192 This definition is inspired by the $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ case.

Comment: But why does it work in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is my question. How do we know that $||v|| = \sqrt{v \cdot v}$, where $||v||$ gives us a notion of distance? This is the fundamental question I am asking.

Comment: Short version: We take the usual Euclidean distance in the plane and just extend it to several dimensions. Note that it is not the only norm available. Norms must satisfy a certain set of properties.

Comment: Maybe you have to show us what you think that the distance is. What properties do you expect that "the distance" satisfies?

Comment: I believe I understand @FeatherWing . That was clear. I guess my fundamental question is digging towards why $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ is a distance from the origin. Perhaps that will be answered in later courses with a proof of Pythagoras and a generalization of it to higher dimensions.

Comment: @SeanRoberson How does $x^2\ge 0$ imply $x\ge 0$, trivially or not?

Comment: @TedShifrin Looks like I got it backwards, sorry. The last bit shouldn't be there, we should just have $x^2 \geq 0$ for real $x$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson does that mean that we can't say that since $||x||^2$ is positive, then $||x||$ is positive? That is just another definition ... ? I honestly was very excited for proof-based math because I thought that we learn the reason behind everything, and that is what excites me.

Comment: What I think you're missing here is the definition of the square root function. If $x>0$, then $\sqrt x$ is defined to be the *unique* *positive* number whose square is $x$. So $\|v\|$ is positive (or possibly zero) by definition.

Comment: When I learned it in elementary, when you take the square root, you get a $\pm$ @TedShifrin

Comment: You get $\pm$ when you solve $x^2=5$ *precisely* because the two solutions are $\sqrt5$ and $-\sqrt5$. One is *by definition* positive, the other its additive inverse. This is an extremely important point you must understand completely.

Comment: So the positive is the one that we use? And $-||v||$ would be its additive inverse? How can it be that there are two solutions but the definition just gives us one thing? Where does the other come from the square root function without the definition?

Comment: This conversation in the comments is far beyond what it should be. A discussion of the meaning of the square root function on the set of real numbers and of how to solve quadratic equations belongs in a different thread. And you should review the meaning of a *function*: It assigns a single (unique) value to each element of its domain.

Answer (score 0):

Given a vector space $V$ equipped  with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\to\textbf{F}$ we can define a norm as you have noticed. More precisely, one has that $\|v\|^{2} = \langle v,v\rangle$ for every $v\in V$. But how do we prove it behaves as a norm indeed? In order to do so, let us remember the properties satisfied by an inner product:

- $\langle u,u\rangle \geq 0$ for every $u\in V$ and $\langle u,u\rangle = 0$ iff $u = 0\in V$,
- $\langle \alpha u,v\rangle = \alpha\langle u,v\rangle$
- $\overline{\langle u,v\rangle} = \langle v,u\rangle$,
- $\langle u + v,w\rangle = \langle u,w\rangle + \langle v,w\rangle$.

for every $u,v,w\in V$ and $\alpha\in\textbf{F}$. Therefore we must prove that:

- $\|u\|\geq 0$ and $\|u\| = 0$ iff $u = 0$,
- $\|\alpha u\| = |\alpha|\|u\|$,
- $\|u + v\| \leq \|u\| + \|v\|$.

for every $u,v\in V$ and $\alpha\in\textbf{F}$.

Indeed, the first properties holds because $\langle u,u\rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle u,u\rangle = 0$ iff $u = 0$.

The second property does also holds because $\langle \alpha u,\alpha u \rangle = \alpha\overline{\alpha}\langle u,u\rangle = |\alpha|^{2}\langle u,u\rangle$.

And finally the last property is true because of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
\begin{align*}
\|u + v\|^{2} & = \langle u + v, u + v\rangle\\\\
& = \langle u,u\rangle + \langle u,v\rangle + \langle v,u\rangle + \langle v,v\rangle\\\\
& =  \|u\|^{2} + 2\text{Re}\langle u,v\rangle + \|v\|^{2}\\\\
& \leq \|u\|^{2} + 2|\langle u,v\rangle| + \|v\|^{2}\\\\
& \leq \|u\|^{2} + 2\|u\|\|v\| + \|v\|^{2}\\\\
& = (\|u\| + \|v\|)^{2}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Given that you have a pre-Hilbert space, you can define orthogonality as you did:
\begin{align*}
u\perp v & \Longleftrightarrow \langle u,v\rangle = 0.
\end{align*}

**EDIT**

Consider that $x = (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$ and $y = (y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3})$ are to vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. According to the cosine's law, one has that the following relations holds:
\begin{align*}
\|x - y\|^{2} = \|x\|^{2} + \|y\|^{2} - 2\|x\|\|y\|\cos(\theta) & 
\end{align*}
where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $y$.

Simplifying the calculations, it results the following expression for the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$:
\begin{align*}
\langle x,y\rangle := x_{1}y_{1} + x_{2}y_{2} + x_{3}y_{3} = \|x\|\|y\|\cos(\theta)
\end{align*}
Consequently, if we take $x = y$, we conclude that $\theta = 0$ and
\begin{align*}
\langle x,x\rangle = x^{2}_{1} + x^{2}_{2} + x^{2}_{3} = \|x\|^{2}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: When you say $a \bar a$ = $|a|^2$, is that a norm or a magnitude? As I understand, it's sometimes called the "modulus" and is the standard inner product for $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The expression $\alpha\overline{\alpha}$ means the product of the scalar $\alpha$ by its conjugate $\overline{\alpha}$, which is indeed one possible scalar product for $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: So if you state $z = a + bi \in \mathbb{C}$, we have $z \bar z = a^2 + b^2$. Is this what is meant by your notation of $|z|^2$? I was just wondering because you used double bars $||$ elsewhere but distinguished it there.

Comment: @user129393192 that's exactly what I meant. With respect to the notation, I think it is just a matter of convention.